Github copilot setup in vscode 2024-07-29 17:57:35.267 [error] [auth] unable to get local issuer certificate
2024-07-29 17:57:35.267 [error] [auth] unable to get local issuer certificate
2024-07-29 17:57:35.437 [error] [default] Error sending telemetry FetchError: unable to get local issuer certificate
at fetch (c:\Users\co28940.vscode\extensions\github.copilot-1.219.0\node_modules@adobe\helix-fetch\src\fetch\index.js:99:11)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at cachingFetch (c:\Users\co28940.vscode\extensions\github.copilot-1.219.0\node_modules@adobe\helix-fetch\src\fetch\index.js:288:16)
at XO.fetch (c:\Users\co28940.vscode\extensions\github.copilot-1.219.0\lib\src\network\helix.ts:96:22) {
type: 'system',
_name: 'FetchError',
code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY',
errno: undefined,
erroredSysCall: undefined
Npm : 10.5.0
Node: 18.20.2
VSCdoe : 1.86.1
I already tried

WIN-CA certificate extension
http.proxyStrictSSL is unchecked
i downloaded local certificates to git config
git config --gloabl http.sslVerify false
But still facing below issue. not able to login to github copilot


does the proxy thing in https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/36894#discussioncomment-7565896 solve your problem? I can write up an answer if so. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Copilotchat-under-Visual-Studio-2022-re/10684177?sort=newest also sounds similar
